# Remove white bg from header/navigation on top of hero image

Tags: html, css, web

Poorly worded question I think, however, I'm working on some coursework just now, it's a very basic HTML website. I'm trying to overlay the logo and the navigation on my Hero image. The issue I'm facing is trying to get the white bg from the header div to be transparent or remove it completely and have the nav and logo at the top of the hero image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope Below CSS might help you.
Add this CSS in your CSS file.

I have used absolute position to overlay the navbar. you can read more in detail about the positions in CSS - https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

```
header {
position: absolute;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you this worked. I'm kinda annoyed I didn't get this - I tried everything but that! When I change the position, it does remove my underline etc on hover. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is just move header section to hero section like that:

```
  <div class="hero">
       <a href="">
    <h1 class="logo"><strong>FOTO.</strong></h1>
  </a>
<header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#hero">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
 <span class="herotext">THE WILD THROUGH A LENSE</span> 

  </div>
```